# Can't bind to 'ng-model' since it isn't a known native property

Tags: angular

Trying to run a todo application from this blog:

http://blog.lambda-it.ch/reactive-data-flow-in-angular-2/

Its code is here: https://github.com/wmaurer/todomvc-ng2-reactive

I am integrating it into my test application - I have my router and added the component to my router config:

```
{ path: '/todo-list', name: 'TodoList', component: TodosComponent },
```

This should not break things.

But when I go to that route, I get error:

```
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngmodel' since it isn't a known native property ("der class=header><h1>todos</h1><input class=new-todo placeholder="What needs to be done?" autofocus [ERROR ->][(ngmodel)]=viewModel.newTodoTitle (keyup.enter)=add($event)></header><section class=main><input type"): TodosComponent@0:143
Property binding ngforOf not used by any directive on an embedded template ("kbox class=toggle-all [checked]=viewModel.allTodosCompleted (click)=toggleAll()><ul class=todo-list>[ERROR ->]<todo-item *ngfor="#todo of viewModel.todos" [todo]=todo (delete)=delete($event) (edit)=edit($event) "): TodosComponent@0:349
Can't bind to 'routerlink' since it isn't a known native property (" }}</strong> item{{ viewModel.numTodosActive == 1 ? '' : 's' }} left</span><ul class=filters><li><a [ERROR ->][routerlink]="['Todos']">All</a></li><li><a [routerlink]="['TodosFiltered', { filter: 'active' }]">Ac"): TodosComponent@0:711
Can't bind to 'routerlink' since it isn't a known native property (" == 1 ? '' : 's' }} left</span><ul class=filters><li><a [routerlink]="['Todos']">All</a></li><li><a [ERROR ->][routerlink]="['TodosFiltered', { filter: 'active' }]">Active</a></li><li><a [routerlink]="['TodosFil"): TodosComponent@0:755
Can't bind to 'routerlink' since it isn't a known native property ("']">All</a></li><li><a [routerlink]="['TodosFiltered', { filter: 'active' }]">Active</a></li><li><a [ERROR ->][routerlink]="['TodosFiltered', { filter: 'completed' }]">Completed</a></li></ul><button class=clear-"): TodosComponent@0:832
Can't bind to 'ngif' since it isn't a known native property ("]="['TodosFiltered', { filter: 'completed' }]">Completed</a></li></ul><button class=clear-completed [ERROR ->]*ngif="viewModel.numTodosCompleted > 0" (click)=removeCompleted()>Clear completed ({{ viewModel.numTo"): TodosComponent@0:943
Property binding ngif not used by any directive on an embedded template ("ive</a></li><li><a [routerlink]="['TodosFiltered', { filter: 'completed' }]">Completed</a></li></ul>[ERROR ->]<button class=clear-completed *ngif="viewModel.numTodosCompleted > 0" (click)=removeCompleted()>Clear"): TodosComponent@0:913
Can't bind to 'ngif' since it isn't a known native property ("$event) (edit)=edit($event) (toggle)=toggle($event)></todo-item></ul></section><footer class=footer [ERROR ->]*ngif="viewModel.numTodos > 0"><span class=todo-count><strong>{{ viewModel.numTodosActive }}</strong>"): TodosComponent@0:522
Property binding ngif not used by any directive on an embedded template ("todo (delete)=delete($event) (edit)=edit($event) (toggle)=toggle($event)></todo-item></ul></section>[ERROR ->]<footer class=footer *ngif="viewModel.numTodos > 0"><span class=todo-count><strong>{{ viewModel.numTo"): TodosComponent@0:501
Can't bind to 'ngif' since it isn't a known native property ("<section [ERROR ->]*ngif=viewModel class=todoapp><header class=header><h1>todos</h1><input class=new-todo placeholder="W"): TodosComponent@0:9
Property binding ngif not used by any directive on an embedded template ("[ERROR ->]<section *ngif=viewModel class=todoapp><header class=header><h1>todos</h1><input class=new-todo place"): TodosComponent@0:0
```

The template looks like this:

```
<section *ngIf="viewModel" class="todoapp">
  <header class="header">
    <h1> todos </h1>
    <input class="new-todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?" autofocus="" [(ngModel)]="viewModel.newTodoTitle" (keyup.enter)="add($event)" />
  </header>
  <section class="main">
    <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-all" [checked]="viewModel.allTodosCompleted" (click)="toggleAll()" />
    <ul class="todo-list">
      <todo-item *ngFor="#todo of viewModel.todos" [todo]="todo" (delete)="delete($event)" (edit)="edit($event)" (toggle)="toggle($event)"></todo-item>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <footer class="footer" *ngIf="viewModel.numTodos > 0">
    <span class="todo-count"><strong>{{ viewModel.numTodosActive }}</strong> item{{ viewModel.numTodosActive == 1 ? '' : 's' }} left</span>
    <ul class="filters">
      <li> <a [routerLink]="['Todos']"> All </a> </li>
      <li> <a [routerLink]="['TodosFiltered', { filter: 'active' }]"> Active </a> </li>
      <li> <a [routerLink]="['TodosFiltered', { filter: 'completed' }]"> Completed </a> </li>
    </ul>
    <button class="clear-completed" *ngIf="viewModel.numTodosCompleted > 0" (click)="removeCompleted()">Clear completed ({{ viewModel.numTodosCompleted }})</button>
  </footer>
</section>
```

I am not able to find what is wrong, the answers which I searched by this err telling nothing new.

What could be wrong here?

**Update:**

I am using minifier in webpack, part of webpack config:

```
module: {
    preLoaders: [
      // { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'tslint-loader', exclude: [ helpers.root('node_modules') ] },
      // TODO(gdi2290): `exclude: [ helpers.root('node_modules/rxjs') ]` fixed with rxjs 5 beta.3 release
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'source-map-loader', exclude: [ helpers.root('node_modules/rxjs') ] }
    ],
    loaders: [
      // Support for .ts files.
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader', exclude: [ /\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/ ] },

      // Support for *.json files.
      { test: /\.json$/,  loader: 'json-loader' },

      // Support for CSS as raw text
      { test: /\.css$/,   loader: 'raw-loader' },

      // support for .html as raw text
      //{ test: /\.html$/,  loader: 'raw-loader', exclude: [ helpers.root('src/index.html') ] },
      { test: /\.html$/, loaders: ['raw-loader', 'html-minify-loader'],
        exclude: [ helpers.root('src/index.html') ] },

      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'raw-loader!sass-loader'
      }

    ]
  },
```

But minifier should not break things imo.

**Update**

I uncommented minifier config, but this still does not help. I am posting whole webpack config file:

```js
// @AngularClass

var webpack = require('webpack');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ForkCheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').ForkCheckerPlugin;

var ENV = process.env.ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
var HMR = helpers.hasProcessFlag('hot');

var metadata = {
  title: 'Angular2 Webpack Starter by @gdi2990 from @AngularClass',
  baseUrl: '/',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3000,
  ENV: ENV,
  HMR: HMR
};
/*
 * Config
 * with default values at webpack.default.conf
 */
module.exports = {
  // static data for index.html
  metadata: metadata,
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  // cache: true,
  debug: true,
  // devtool: 'eval' // for faster builds use 'eval'

  // our angular app
  entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'main': './src/main.ts'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
  },

  // Config for our build files
  output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },

  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      // { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'tslint-loader', exclude: [ helpers.root('node_modules') ] },
      // TODO(gdi2290): `exclude: [ helpers.root('node_modules/rxjs') ]` fixed with rxjs 5 beta.3 release
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'source-map-loader', exclude: [ helpers.root('node_modules/rxjs') ] }
    ],
    loaders: [
      // Support for .ts files.
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader', exclude: [ /\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/ ] },

      // Support for *.json files.
      { test: /\.json$/,  loader: 'json-loader' },

      // Support for CSS as raw text
      { test: /\.css$/,   loader: 'raw-loader' },

      // support for .html as raw text
      /*{ test: /\.html$/,  loader: 'raw-loader', exclude: [ helpers.root('src/index.html') ] },*/
      { test: /\.html$/, loaders: ['raw-loader', 'html-minify-loader'],
        exclude: [ helpers.root('src/index.html') ]
      },

      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'raw-loader!sass-loader'
      }

    ]
  },


  'html-minify-loader': {
    empty: true,        // KEEP empty attributes
    cdata: true,        // KEEP CDATA from scripts
    comments: true,     // KEEP comments
    dom: {                            // options of !(htmlparser2)[https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2]
      lowerCaseAttributeNames: false,      // do not call .toLowerCase for each attribute name (Angular2 use camelCase attributes)
    }
  },

  plugins: [
    new ForkCheckerPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(true),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: ['main', 'vendor', 'polyfills'], minChunks: Infinity }),
    // static assets
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([ { from: 'src/assets', to: 'assets' } ]),
    // generating html
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: 'src/index.html', chunksSortMode: 'none',
      minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        collapseInlineTagWhitespace: true,
        // removeTagWhitespace: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true
      }  }),



    // Environment helpers (when adding more properties make sure you include them in custom-typings.d.ts)
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'ENV': JSON.stringify(metadata.ENV),
      'HMR': HMR
    }),

  ],

  // Other module loader config

  // our Webpack Development Server config
  tslint: {
    emitErrors: false,
    failOnHint: false,
    resourcePath: 'src',
  },
  devServer: {
    port: metadata.port,
    host: metadata.host,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    watchOptions: {
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
      poll: 1000
    }
  },
  node: {
    global: 'window',
    process: true,
    crypto: 'empty',
    module: false,
    clearImmediate: false,
    setImmediate: false
  }
};
```

Can you see what is wrong here?

Comment: Are you using some kind of html minifier? Your template is fine, but the error points to ngModel being lowercased. Actually everything is lowercased in the error message.

Comment: @DariusV You have to tell me in the answer that it didn't work, I don't get notifications when the question has been edited.

Comment: I've updated the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see in your question, you're using [html-minify-loader](https://github.com/bestander/html-minify-loader).

In the repository you can see this [example](https://github.com/bestander/html-minify-loader#example)

```
'html-minify-loader': {

     dom: {
            lowerCaseAttributeNames: false   
            // do not call .toLowerCase for each attribute name (Angular2 use camelCase attributes)
     }
}
```

So by adding that option in your webpack config you should be fine.

**Edit**

Make sure you're using the latest version of the plugin, I tested it (with your config) and it worked perfectly.

- html-minify-loader v1.1.0
- minimize v1.8.1 (installed by html-minify-loader)

Comment: "html-minify-loader": "^1.1.0", and then in node_modules found html-minify-loader and in package.json its "minimize": "^1.8.1". So any other ideas?

Comment: I made a repo with a few steps to make it fail and make it work, check it out [here](https://github.com/ericmartinezr/angular2-webpack-html-minify/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 1):

Add up to Eric Martinez answer:

Probably I did not restart the server by stopping and running command

```
npm run server
```

After restarting - there is no such error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved the issue for production webpack builds that use html-loader :

```
{
    test: /\.html$/,
    loader: 'html-loader',
    options: {
        minimize: {
            caseSensitive: true
        }
    }
}
```