# No provider for t! (e -> t) only on minified Angular2

Tags: angular

When using [(ngModel)] on an input element, inside form which has *ngIf, I'm getting this error.

```
angular2.min.js:17 EXCEPTION: No provider for t! (e -> t)
```

This only happens when using angular2.min.js version. When switching to angular2.dev.js or angular2.js it works without an error.

Please see this plunkr (try to switch angular2.min.js to angular2.js in index.html and see the error dissapears):
http://plnkr.co/edit/ze5khGAjTTX1OGQcHhZ4

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6413

Comment: why it happens only on minified version? is it safe to assume that this is a minification problem and I can use the full version for now?

Comment: No, but there are lot of issues with minification. The Angular team is working on it, but the issue is already since about beta.1 AFAIR. But I think they are close to getting it fixed.

Comment: You can check the workaround mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36103832/cant-bind-to-ng-model-since-it-isnt-a-known-native-property/36103936#36103936

Comment: Thanks! Will use the full version for now.